# A word like `dichotomy` but not necessarily mutually exclusive

Tags: word-choice, terminology, mathematics

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomy):

> A **dichotomy** is a partition of a whole (or a set) into two parts (subsets). In other words, this couple of parts must be
>
> - jointly exhaustive: everything must belong to one part or the other, and
> - mutually exclusive: nothing can belong simultaneously to both parts.

I am looking for a similar word which is still logically *jointly exhaustive* but not necessarily *mutually exclusive*.

Comment: My first thought was mutually inclusive, but that implies that the two sets **have** to have some overlap, although not complete overlap. Would that be too strong a word for what you want?

Comment: If something can fall into *more* than one set, then to at least some extent, those sets / divisions / categories are ***orthogonal***. Which seems a bit meaningless if those sets are "jointly exhaustive" (I assume that means *everything* must fall into ***at least one of the sets***).

Comment: Why are you looking for a singe word? What is the context of your question? How would you use this word in one or more sample sentences? Is this a technical question (e.g., related to computer programming) or a general question about English language and usage? Please edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: What is wrong with simply *jointly exhaustive* ?

Comment: ...or 'overlapping' (which pragmatically implies not identical.

Answer (score 1):

In math, a collection of sets which may overlap, and whose union contains the "whole" in your question, is called the **[cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(topology))** of that whole. Note that this is not jointly exhaustive: elements might be in the cover, and not in the whole (the cover is "bigger" than the whole). A jointly exhaustive cover would be known as a [minimal cover](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimalCover.html).

In less formal contexts, I have heard "cover" used the same way.

Comment: Not being a professional mathematician, I found those links a bit hard going. It certainly looks like you've nailed it, but I have to say this looks like something that should have been asked on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A layman's guide to math terms is so elusive a beast, that creating one might be tantamount to a Hilbert Problem - but there I go, making math references again. // I got suspicious that Name might be looking for a technical term, given their word choice, but I'm not certain.

Comment: It's all a bit beyond me, but my understanding is "set theory" and multi-dimensionality are pretty hot stuff these days. I'm guessing that *minimal cover* is (or *will be*) central to AI neural nets working with natural language processing & intelligent free-form information retrieval. We've already seen that the "hidden layers" in AI visual recognition nets spontaneously identify lines, angles, borders, etc. I'd be fascinated to see if an NLP net could spontaneously construct an entire new "artificial natural language" (ideally, specifically biased towards being easy for *anyone* to learn).